# Node was not found error in javascript on changing the variable value

Tags: javascript, php

I am using following javascript code(simplified version) for removing the child elements from my dropdownlist.

```
overmenu="Advies_opgevolgdmenu";
var parentobj = document.getElementById('body');
var childobj =  document.getElementById(overmenu);
parentobj.removeChild(childobj);
```

Html code:

```
$type="Advies_opgevolgdmenu";

<body id="body">
<ul id="<?php echo $type ?>" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important">
</body>
```

previously it was working fine when overmenu="Adviesopgevolgdmenu",but when i inserted a underscore in between the overmenu variable start getting the following error:

IN firefox:

**Node was not found
[Break On This Error]

parentobj.removeChild(childobj);**

In chrome:

**uncaught Error: NotFoundError: DOM Exception 8**

What I am doing wrong and also what are the common reasons for this error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look at the rendered source and search for both ids. It's possible the one ID was already in use.

Comment: i already checked in firebug ,everything is fine.

Comment: Could you provide us with a jsfiddle, of the rendered html and js, which causes the error?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/aY4z6/ This seems to be working perfectly. if you move the ul outside of id="body", you get that error.

Comment: @Kao ul is inside the body only.

Comment: Well, I would need more info in order to be helpful then. As stated, my fiddle works, using the markup you provided.

Comment: I wonder if it comes down to the lack of a closing </ul> tag?  Maybe some browsers confuse if the <ul /> is inside the <body /> if there's no closing tag.

Comment: brian i rechecked the closing ul tag also and its fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
  var overmenu="Advies_opgevolgdmenu";
  var childobj =  document.getElementById(overmenu);
  childobj.parentNode.removeChild(childobj);
```

Comment: console.log(childobj),childobj is null or DOM object?

Comment: on using console.log i got <ul id="Wijze_contactmenu" class="mcdropdown_menu" style="z-index: 997 !important"> which is correct but still its showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you don't have an element with an ID of "body"?

I noticed that you're using this code to get (I assume) the body of the document:

```
var parentobj = document.getElementById('body');
```

You may want something more like:

```
var parentobj = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]
```

which will select all the  elements on the page, and return the first element of the resulting array.

Comment: i do have body with the same id and while using your another code getting the parentobj not found error

Comment: Interesting, it works for me on this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sxnjC  What browser are you seeing the error in?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't replicate the problem in Firefox on the codepen :(  Maybe try adding a closing tag to the <ul>?

What happens if you take the underscore ('_') back out of the name?  Does it start working again?

Comment: yeas brian the underscore is only causing the issue,earlier it was working fine,the original code is of nearly 4000 lines so i cant copy whole code here.